# Cloudfront to APIGateway/Lambda cookies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, cookies

We have an AWS Lambda API server that is placed behind an APIGateway endpoint, and a React.js client that lives in an S3 bucket and served through Cloudfront.

When the user logs in the API server sends a cookie in the Set-Cookie header, but the browser doesn't send it back in subsequent requests. We've tried it on Chrome 90 and the latest Firefox, but no dice.

After log-in, the React code does a `fetch` like this:

```js
fetch(`${url}/api/<blahblah>`, {
            method: 'GET',
            credentials: 'include',
            headers: new Headers({
                accept: 'application/json'
            })
```

But the browser appears to decide that the cookie doesn't match and so doesn't send it in the request.

I have tried all manner of flags in the `Set-Cookie`, and the browsers are happy to store it with the initial response.

Currently the cookie looks like this:
`<cookie contents>; Expires=Fri, 21 May 2021 12:00:32 GMT; Max-Age=86400; HttpOnly; Path=/; SameSite=Lax`
Although I have tried setting the domain explicitly, setting the `Secure` flag with `SameSite=None`, removing the `HttpOnly` flag, and probably a dozen other combinations. The browsers all say that the cookie is valid, with no warnings or anything. Both the frontend and backend are using HTTPS, so `Secure; SameSite=None` should work, right?

The response headers from the server include `access-control-allow-credentials: true`, and `access-control-allow-origin` is set to the right Cloudfront URL.

I have had it working once on a localhost to localhost request, but even that doesn't seem to work any more.

What have I missed? Is it an AWS setting that needs changing? Is it the `fetch` call that is missing an option?